# GhostScript generated PDF shows hidden text

Tags: ghostscript

I have some postscript files that are hiding text by showing white text on top of it.

Here is a very simple example to illustrate the issue:

```
%!

/Times-Roman findfont
20 scalefont
setfont

newpath
0 setgray
72 72 moveto
(Hello, world!) show   % Show some text
72 72 moveto
1 setgray
(Hello, world!) show   % Hide some text

showpage
```

If I send this file directly to the printer, the hidden text is not printed.

However, when I use GhostScript (version 9.21) to convert this PS to a PDF, I can still see the outline of the text a little bit. This was the command I used:

```
gswin32.exe -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sOutputFile=C:\temp\output.pdf test.ps
```

I also tried setting the colors to CMYK with but that didn't help.

How can I conifgure GhostScript to generate a PDF without showing this 'hidden' text?

kind regards,
Maarten Coene

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well obviously the text isn't hidden, its been overdrawn in white.

I can see three likely possibilities and without seeing what you do, I can't decide which is happening.

1) Obviously the PDF consumer will have to turn black and white gray specifications into 'something else', usually RGB but possibly CMYK depending on whether you are viewing the PDF file on screen or printing it. If you see the entire solid text, but faintly, then that's what's happening.

2) Possibly the PDF consumer doesn't match up the two sets of text precisely. If you see partial outlines of the text, then that's what's going on.

3) Or (here's the sneaky bit) possibly your viewer uses some kind of anti-aliasing. If the black underlying text is anti-aliased, but the white isn't, then you'll see a sort of 'halo'. The entire outline of the text will be visible, probably in a faint gray, but the interior will be white.

I took your example file, and ran it through the current HEAD version of Ghostscript, writing the PDF file uncompressed and the resulting page content is:

```
5 0 obj
<</Length 6 0 R>>
stream
q 0.1 0 0 0.1 0 0 cm
/R7 gs
0 g
q
10 0 0 10 0 0 cm BT
/R8 20 Tf
1 0 0 1 72 72 Tm
(Hello, world!)Tj
ET
Q
1 g
q
10 0 0 10 0 0 cm BT
/R8 20 Tf
1 0 0 1 72 72 Tm
(Hello, world!)Tj
ET
Q
Q
endstream
endobj
```

As you can see, this maintains the pure black and pure white colour specifications for the text (the ExtGState simply sets the overprint mode to 1) and positions each piece of text in precisely the same place.

My guess is that your viewer is using anti-aliasing to draw the black text, but not the white text. FWIW Adobe Acrobat does not show this behaviour for me.

Comment: Thanks for your excellent explanation! :-) After changing the 'Smooth Text' rendering option in Adobe Acrobat Reader, the black font isn't displayed any longer... but this illustrates that this 'white-font' hack to hide some text is not a very solid solution since it depends on settings of the pdf viewer. Do you have any suggestions how we could do this in a better way?

Comment: Use text rendering mode 3 ? You do realise that anything you do which involves text can be instantly defeated by someone like me who can decode the file ? It also leaves the text searchable in a PDF viewer, and copy/paste will work, so simply 'select all' would allow the user to see and copy it. Perhaps you could explain why you want the text to be invisible but still present ?

Comment: In our postscript files, we have some logic to check that there is always an amount of empty space after the last line of text on the last page (to ensure there is enough space to put a signature on it). So after printing the last line, we check if there is enough space available, if not, we 'revert' printing the last page by making the text invisible and retry again with less text on that page and add an extra page with the rest of the text. Perhaps there are better solutions ... ? Here is a simplified example of our ps file: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2a01c51c41f513ed4ab88b4c3dc1b063

Comment: Well realistically, the correct way to do this is to check the size of the required text, and see if it leaves enough space for a signature **before** you draw the text. You can determine the size of the text easily enough by something like : "(..text to show..) true charpath flattenpath pathbbox" You are only interested in the y direction, so you can then do "sub 3 1 roll pop pop" leaving you the size of the text in the y direction. If the remaining space less that text is insufficient, then start a new page and then draw it, otherwise just draw it and continue.

Comment: Thanks Ken, I managed to determine the size of the text without showing it :-) So no need to make it 'invisible' again...